# is it possible to run selenium script on mobile web without using Appium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

is it possible to run selenium script on mobile web without using Appium?

I want to know when Appium is required? for mobile web or for the mobile native app or mobile hybrid app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Appium` required for all mobile app(web/native/hybrid), `Appium` server required for communicating between mobile and test script.

Comment: How much code re-writing is required to run the same tests for Mobile Platforms?